# how to display no records found message in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I searched for above query and got so many answers but none of that answer is helpful for me. Hence Posting this question.

I have a gridview with Two dates.

1. From
2. To

When I select two dates and if data between two dates is available in database then it will get displayed on gridview. If data is not available then I want to show a Message on `Label` i.e. "No Records Found"

Here is my code.

```
 myConn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select User_id , LoginDate from LoginLog where LoginDate between ('" + TextBox1.Text + "') and ('" + TextBox2.Text + "')", myConn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 sda.Fill(dt);
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;

 if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     GridView1.DataBind();
 }
 else
 {
     Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";
 }

 myConn.Close();
```

Comment: `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">`. But you have to call `DataBind()` for that, so remove `GridView1.Rows.Count > 0`

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your ASPX file :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" BorderStyle="Ridge" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found." EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="Red">
```

**And your CS will be :**

```
myConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select User_id , LoginDate from LoginLog where LoginDate between
                                 ('" + TextBox1.Text + "') and ('" + TextBox2.Text + "')", myConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
myConn.Close();
```

**Or you can see this link:**
[Show asp.net Gridview Header when no data/records found](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/15/Show-aspnet-Gridview-Header-when-no-data-records-found.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in gridview control

```
EmptyDataText="No Records Found"
```

Comment: I have a Label and it's id is Lab4 I want to display message on in that label

Comment: but label is outside the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether DataTable contains values or not.

```
 myConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select User_id , LoginDate from LoginLog where LoginDate between
                                 ('" + TextBox1.Text + "') and ('" + TextBox2.Text + "')", myConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";
}
myConn.Close();
```

hope this helps. Regards :)

Comment: I tried this code but now i am getting Label's output correctly plus gridview complete data, even data is not available between two dates.

Comment: Try if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";  GridView1.visible = false;
}

Comment: Now Gridview is completely disable even if data is present in database. Now label is working fine

Comment: What I would do is retrieving data via SqlDaraReader. Write separate function to retrieve data and return a data table. Assign that data table to the datagridview.Source. Instead using dataGridView.dataBind use that method

Comment: Check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";
}
myConn.Close();

private void Retrieve()
        {
              if(loadPositions() != null){
                dgvEmployeePositions.DataSource = loadPositions();
              }
              else{
                  Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";
              }


        }

 private DataTable loadPositions()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();;
            myConn.Open(); 
            String q = "your query here";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, connectionString);
            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(r.hasRows){
                dt.Load(r); 
                return dt;          
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }               


        }
```